# Get all possible list of perfect squares formed by breaking a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Get all possible permutations of list of perfect squares formed by breaking a number.

**Ex** : If N = 14 then lists are [1,1,4,4,4], [1,4,9] , [1,1,1,1,1,9] , [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

Output lists can be in any order

I got this code but it can only give perfect squares in order.

```
l = []
b = int(input())
for i in range(1,b):
    k = i*i
    l.append(k)
    if sum(l)>b:
        l.pop()
        break
    else:
        pass
print(l)
```

help me..

Comment: Question to check on my understanding.  For N = 14 aren't there 6 lists (rather than 4) namely: `[(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 (1, 4, 9),
 (1, 1, 4, 4, 4)]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code result in 6 possibilities for N = 14, rather than posted 4.

**Code**

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
from pprint import pprint

# flatten and powerset from
#   https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
def flatten(list_of_lists):
    "Flatten one level of nesting"
    return chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists)

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def solve(n):
  " Get all possible permutations of list of perfect squares formed by breaking a number "
  squares = (i*i for i in range(1, int(b**0.5)+1)) # squares that can be used
  multiples = ([i]*int(b//i) for i in squares)     # repetition of squares that can be used
  numbers = flatten(multiples)                     # flatten to single list

  # Compute set of powerset, and take results which sum to b
  return [x for x in set(powerset(numbers)) if sum(x) == b]
```

**Test**

```
b = int(input('input number: '))  # Enter 14
result = solve(b)
pprint(result)
```

*Output*

```
input number: 14
[(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 (1, 4, 9),
 (1, 1, 4, 4, 4)]
```

**Restrict Maximum Length**

```
def solve_maxlen(n, maxlen):
  " Get all possible permutations of list of perfect squares formed by breaking a number "
  squares = (i*i for i in range(1, int(b**0.5)+1)) # squares that can be used
  multiples = ([i]*int(b//i) for i in squares)     # repetition of squares that can be used
  numbers = flatten(multiples)                     # flatten to single list

  # Compute set of powerset, and take results which sum to b
  return [x for x in set(powerset(numbers)) if sum(x) == b and len(x) <= maxlen] 

pprint(solve_maxlen(14, 6))
```

*Output*

```
[(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9), (1, 4, 9), (1, 1, 4, 4, 4)]
```

Comment: Thanks this solution is helpful. Can you modify the code by restricting length of every list to variable 'a'.

Comment: Thank you @DarryIG

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

up_to = int(input())

def is_perfect_square(number):
  squared = pow(number, 0.5)
  return int(squared) == squared

perfect_squares = filter(is_perfect_square, range(1, up_to))
permutations = list(itertools.permutations(perfect_squares))

print(permutations)
```

The output is:

```
[(1, 4, 9), (1, 9, 4), (4, 1, 9), (4, 9, 1), (9, 1, 4), (9, 4, 1)]
```

Comment: That's just one result in different orders. You are missing the other 3 options...

Comment: @Tomerikoo--do you think there are 4 or 6 options (see my question comment)?